# com.microsoft.azure:azure-sqldb-spark bulkCopyBatchSize don't work

Tags: java, sql-server, apache-spark, columnstore

I use the microsoft Java API: azure.sqldb.spark to bulk insert a spark dataframe.
I wanted to increase the batch size but I find that the input size of each partition is 32.1 MB (almost 120000 Records) for any value of bulkCopyBatchSize. see below a screenshot of the spark interface.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/GZi5S.png

Here is the used configuration  (I even tried with small value of bulkCopyBatchSize and I find that the input size is always 32.1 MB) (I use a local spark)

```
   java.util.Map<String, Object> map = new java.util.HashMap<String, Object>();
    map.put("url", resultProperties.dbServer);
    map.put("databaseName", resultProperties.dbName);
    map.put("user", resultProperties.dbUser);
    map.put("password", resultProperties.dbPassword);
    map.put("dbTable", "dbo.RESULT_DATA");
    map.put("bulkCopyBatchSize", "1048576");
    map.put("bulkCopyTableLock", "false");
    map.put("bulkCopyTimeout", "600");
    Map<String, Object> props = JavaConverters.mapAsScalaMapConverter(map).asScala().toMap(Predef.$conforms());
    config = new com.microsoft.azure.sqldb.spark.config.SqlDBConfigBuilder(props).build();
```

Comment: Isn't the 32.1MB the DataFrame partition size, not the Bulk Copy batch size?

Comment: Normally the size of each partition must be equal to the bulkcopybatchsize because for each partition it will have a bulk insert request on the database

Comment: But you can bulk insert a large number of rows in smaller batches.

Comment: In my case, I have to use a large batch size because the table ,where I insert data, is columnstore indexed. I must avoid going through the delta store because it causes a deadlock victim in some cases